# Mysql PHP advanced condition

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I would like to know if the following query with brackets really works. I have three conditions separated with `OR`, so I would like to know if it really takes only one of the three conditions or more than one condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_ref` WHERE `tbl_name` LIKE `$table_choice` AND ( ( i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1 ) OR ( i1<=d2 AND d2 <=d1  ) OR ( i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your query with indenting, which makes it easier (for me at least) to follow the logic:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_ref` 
WHERE `tbl_name` LIKE `$table_choice` AND 
  (
    ((i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1) OR (i1<=d2 AND d2 <=d1)) OR
    (i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1)
  )
```

I'll number the conditions:

1. `tbl_name LIKE $table_choice`
2. `((i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1) OR (i1<=d2 AND d2 <=d1))`
3. `(i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1)`

A row will be included if any of the following happens:

- **1** and **2** and **3** are true
- **1** and **2** are true
- **1** and **3** are true

Basically, **1** always has to be true, then either (or both) of **2** and **3** must be true.

---

Also, if you're using the `mysql` PHP functions your code will be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use PDO or mysqli instead. More information [here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and a bunch of other places.

---

**Addendum**: followup comment suggests the OP wants an "exclusive OR" condition:

> > no the three condition I meant are : 1 (i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1) , 2 (i1<=d2 AND d2 <=d1), 3 (i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1) , and I only want a row to be included if one of those three is true

MySQL has an `XOR` operator, but `XOR` is meant for only two conditions. It gets complicated very quickly when dealing with more than two. I'd suggest something like this (still including the `tbl_name` condition):

```
WHERE tbl_name LIKE '$table_choice'
 AND 1 =
   CASE WHEN i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN i1<=d2 AND d2<=d1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I'll number the conditions again:

1. `tbl_name LIKE $table_choice`
2. `(i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1)`
3. `(i1<=d2 AND d2<=d1)`
4. `(i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1)`

The `WHERE` clause above will include a row if the following happens:

- 1 and 2 are true
- 1 and 3 are true
- 1 and 4 are true

Comment: no the three condition I meant are : **1** `(i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1)` , **2** `(i1<=d2 AND d2 <=d1)`, **3** `(i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1)` , and I only want a row to be included if one of those three is true

Comment: @Falcon - please see the addendum to my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes that's it , thank you very match ! I didn't know this was possible  ^^

Comment: I have a question, what if all the three conditions are true ?

Comment: it should still include the row even if there's more than one correct condition

Comment: I used the condition `AND ((i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1) OR (i1<=d2 AND d2<=d1) OR (i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1))` and I think it works fine, up till now the results are logical

Answer (score 0):

Your query is the same as using:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_ref` WHERE `tbl_name` LIKE `$table_choice` AND ((i1<=i2 AND i2<=d1) OR (i1<=d2 AND d2<=d1) OR (i2<=i1 AND d2<=d1))
```

Comment: I know, but does it take in account the condition correctly or not

Comment: as long as one of those 3 within parantheses are true, and tbl_name is like $table_choice it will return a result

Comment: yeah it works fine, I just got one the conditions wrong that's why I got weird results :)